# Group categories by IDs python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-structures

I have a table ( data frame) as follows

```
--------------------------
|ID    | code  | happened|
--------------------------
|  1   | A     |    1    |
|  1   | B     |    1    |
|  1   | A     |    1    |
|  2   | A     |    0    |
|  2   | c     |    0    |
|  2   | D     |    0    |
|  3   | E     |    1    |
|  3   | E     |    1    |
```

The `happened` doesnt change for `ID`

```
--------------------------    
|ID    |  list | happened |
---------------------------
| 1    |  A,B,A| 1        |
| 2    | A,C,D | 0        |
| 3    | E, E  | 1        |
```

The `list` should keep the sequence of the code list. Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `agg`

```
df.groupby('ID',as_index=False).agg({'code': lambda x : ','.join(x),'happened':'first'})
Out[911]: 
   ID   code  happened
0   1  A,B,A         1
1   2  A,c,D         0
2   3    E,E         1
```

Comment: Awesome! It worked! what is this `lambds x :`  mean?

Comment: @Sai it is like a self-def function

Answer (score 1):

An approach using `pivot_table`:

```
(df.pivot_table(
    index='ID', values='code', aggfunc=','.join).join(df.groupby('ID').happened.first()))
```

```
     code  happened
ID
1   A,B,A         1
2   A,c,D         0
3     E,E         1
```

Comment: yours is as similar as the other one but with `pivot_table`